# Obtain the current value when parsing an html file with bokeh sliders

Tags: python, slider, bokeh, pyquery

I am using bokeh to plot my math functions created with python/numpy.

I would like to use sliders as shown in

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/server_gallery/sliders_server.html

Once I create the html file with the plot, I would like to select different values on the sliders which modify the plot and then read back the chosen values in into python to use it for other manipulations.

What is the best way to read the chosen value on the slider from the html file back into python ?

I saw pyquery could be useful, but I cannot really figure that out.

Any suggestions would be appreciated based on above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There are two slider examples in the bokeh repo, where the slider is connected back to python via the bokeh server.

- [Sliders App](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0c78cf646ec95d3c003c714c35a388db4b4ad834/examples/app/sliders_applet/sliders_app.py)
- [Taylor server](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0c78cf646ec95d3c003c714c35a388db4b4ad834/examples/glyphs/taylor_server.py)

If this isn't what you were after, can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I guess I should elaborate more. It is the Sliders App - first bullet item - what I would like to do is to read the current value that I select by sliding back and forth the cursor of the slider. I thought to use an html parser, but as I open the example as a source code, it wasn't able to locate the value in the page. I suspect I might some more complex extraction commands ... since I am a real beginner, I am not sure. My final goal is to read back into the python code the value selected and use that value for other functions later in the python code. Thanks

Comment: @geppo, I'm afraid I'm not understanding. The examples do read back in the values from the slider. e.g. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0c78cf646ec95d3c003c714c35a388db4b4ad834/examples/app/sliders_applet/sliders_app.py#L118 - the function has the new value of the slider in argument `new`.

Comment: OK, I think I am not explaining myself well, let me try to copy the code

Comment: whatever is in he from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show 
from bokeh.models.actions import Callback
import os
import json
os.chdir("c:\\anaconda\\rfpack\\sipi\\primitive")
output_file("callback.html")
x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

Comment: more on the code ---callback = Callback(args=dict(source=source), code="""
        var data = source.get('data');
        var f = cb_obj.get('value')
        x = data['x']
        y = data['y']
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
        }
        source.trigger('change');
    """)
slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power", callback=callback)
layout = vform(slider, plot)
show(layout)

Comment: Now, if you copy the two sections above, the first one starting from "from bokeh.io" and the secodn one starting from "callback" and you put them together in a py file and execute it, you get an html file with a slider. I would like to be able to grab the value that the slider select and bring it back into the above code...

Comment: I can't reason about this. Can you update your original question and use syntax highlighting.

Comment: @ birdsarah thank you. It turns out that what I am asking can be done using bokeh-server. "A static HTML file and the state of the slider is inside a web browser and never reflected back to the HTML file. What you should be doing is to use bokeh-server." Thanks. Item closed

Answer (score 0):

A static HTML file and the state of the slider is inside a web browser and never reflected back to the HTML file. What you should be doing is to use bokeh-server - answered via bokeh-google group